# Objects and my code

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: 'bill',
        lastName: 'Green',
        number: ('812381293'),
        address : ['chicken st 12','rigth corner']
        }
    steve: {
       firstName: 'steve',
        lastName: 'Brown',
        number: ('812222381293'), 
        address : ['chicken st 12','rigth corner']
        }
};
var list = function(friends) {
    for (var name in friends) {
        console.log(name);
 }
}
var search = function (friends) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        if ( friends[key].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        } 
    } 
}
```

I have a syntax error:

> Unexpected identifier

Whats wrong with my code?

here's what I needed to do in the current task:

> Define a function search that takes a single argument, name. If the argument passed to the function matches any of the first names in friends, it should log that friend's contact information to the console and return it.

Comment: You're missing a comma between `}` and `steve: {`

Comment: "Define a function search **that takes a single argument, name**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
    }, // <--- this!
steve: {
```

and change the parameter of the function to `name`, because you should looking for it.

```
var search = function (name) { // change friends to name!
    for (var key in friends) {
        if ( friends[key].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        } 
    } 
}
```

Working code:

```js
var friends = {
        bill: {
            firstName: 'bill',
            lastName: 'Green',
            number: ('812381293'),
            address: ['chicken st 12', 'rigth corner']
        },
        steve: {
            firstName: 'steve',
            lastName: 'Brown',
            number: ('812222381293'),
            address: ['chicken st 12', 'rigth corner']
        }
    },
    list = function (friends) {
        for (var name in friends) {
            console.log(name);
        }
    },
    search = function (name) {
        for (var key in friends) {
            if (friends[key].firstName === name) {
                console.log(friends[key]);
                return friends[key];
            }
        }
    };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(search('steve'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I got a new problem XD  : " It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Steve "

Comment: because `'steve' !== 'Steve'`!

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it  :\ Also i do not need to use this (document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(search('steve'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');) in my code .

Comment: the `JSON.stringify(...)` is for the displaying of the whole object. the steve problem: if you like to compare strings which have upper and lower case, the i suggest to conver both string to either upper or lower case and then compare them.